# Adding radio buttons to Laravel Spark - Vue component page

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, laravel-spark

I tried to stay away from the Vue components of Spark as much as possible but I discovered I had to implement a certain mail settings so I can't hold it much longer.

Luckily the Spark documentation contains a small cookbook for adding profile fields: 
https://spark.laravel.com/docs/4.0/adding-profile-fields

Most parts are within my (limited PHP) comfort zone:

First the blade php:

Mail settings

```
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="profile" v-model="form.type" name="profile">Profile</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="website" v-model="form.type" name="website">Website</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="combined" v-model="form.type" name="combined">Combined</label>

        <span class="help-block" v-show="form.errors.has('mail-settings')">
          @{{ form.errors.get('mail-settings') }}
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Which is integrated:

```
 <!-- Update Mail settings -->
   @include('settings.profile.update-mail-settings')
```

So as can be seen in the previous code block, I wish to store the result of 3 radio buttons. 
However the linked Vue js file is giving my headaches:

```
Vue.component('update-mail-settings', {
    props: ['user'],

    data() {
        return {
            form: new SparkForm({
                profile: ''
                website: ''
                combined: ''
            })
        };
    },

    mounted() {
        this.form.mailsettings = this.user.mailsettings;
    },

    methods: {
        update() {
            Spark.put('/settings/profile/mail-settings', this.form)
                .then(response => {
                    Bus.$emit('updateUser');
                });
        }
    }
});
```

But how on earth do I integrate the radio buttons in the SparkForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue, data binding occurs when you v-model to the object by name. Or in other words, you call v-model="object.property"  on an input.  When the user fills out the form, the value of form.type will match the form input.   So simply change your form object to read:

```
 data() {
   return {
    form: new SparkForm({
        type: ''    <-  this can now be v-modeled to "form.type"
    })
  };
},
```

Your radio buttons don't need to change because they are bound correctly: v-model="form.type"

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio

Comment: Super! That worked perfect. I did run into another issue but at least the radio buttons are now working. Thanks a lot.